# Parsing an XML to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsmutablearray

I'm parsing an XML file, everything is perfect and I'm seeing the file with `NSLog`, I'm seeing the result of the parsing also, but when I transfer the tag that I need to a `NSMutableArray`, the result is strange.

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName

 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"nom"]) {
        // displays the Content of the tag
        NSLog(soapResults);
        // add the content of the tag to the NSMutableArray
        [mySuppliers addObject:soapResults];
        // displays the NSMutable Array
        NSLog(@"array: %@", mySuppliers);
        [soapResults setString:@""];
        elementFound = FALSE;
        // displays the count of the NSMutable Array
        NSLog(@"NUMBER %d", [mySuppliers count]);
 }
 ....
```

The output is:

```
2012-12-16 22:00:03.140 StartProj[11698:c07] ABC
2012-12-16 22:00:03.140 StartProj[11698:c07] array: (
    "ABC"
)
2012-12-16 22:00:03.140 StartProj[11698:c07] NUMBER 1
2012-12-16 22:00:03.141 StartProj[11698:c07] ABBOTT
2012-12-16 22:00:03.141 StartProj[11698:c07] array: (
    "ABBOTT ",
    "ABBOTT "
)
2012-12-16 22:00:03.141 StartProj[11698:c07] NUMBER 2
2012-12-16 22:00:03.142 StartProj[11698:c07] ACCESSORIES
2012-12-16 22:00:03.142 StartProj[11698:c07] array: (
    ACCESSORIES,
    ACCESSORIES,
    ACCESSORIES
)
2012-12-16 22:00:03.142 StartProj[11698:c07] NUMBER 3
```

Comment: Where you allocated the array.

Comment: do you get the solution ??

Answer (score 1):

For xml parsing try to use rapturexml which is very simple.

https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

Answer (score 0):

better can allocate NSmutabledictionary after add each and every element to dictinary finally dictionary items shift to nsmutable array.
[image]

[image]

[image]